# alignment issue while zooming page

Tags: html, css

please see the code its working fine until am zooming the page...after zooming page the page gets distorted with its horizontal menus coliding together please seee the code it would be great if anybody can tellme what "not to do " instead just providing correct css part for this i am new in this and want to learn aspects rathern than copying from various sources
here is the CSS part ..

```
body{ background-color:#603}
div#hor ul{ position:relative; left:16%; }
 div#hor li,div#ver li{  float:left;list-style-type:none; background-color:#603; border-radius:22px; margin:5px; }
div#hor a,div#ver a{text-decoration:none; 
 padding-left:32px; padding-right:32px;
 font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive; 
 line-height::100px;padding-right: 32px;
 padding-left: 32px;
 display: block;
 line-height: 40px;
 color:#fff;
}
div#hor a:hover{background-color:#fff;color: #603;border-radius:22px; 
    }
    div#hor a:focus{background-color:#fff;color:#603;border-radius:22px; font-weight:bold;
    }
    div#ver{  position:relative; top:100px;}
    div#ver ul{ position:relative; left:-50%; float:left;  }
    div#ver li{ float:none; margin-bottom:20px;}

    div#ver a:hover,div#ver a:focus{border-radius:22px;background-color:#fff;color: #603}

    div#ver a:focus{ font-weight:bold; }


  # here is the html part ...#



  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"  />


    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="hor">
    <ul>
    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ver"> 
    <ul>
    <li ><a href="#">Java</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Asp.net</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
    <li><a  href="#">Iphone</a></li>
    </ul>

     </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your `div` settings are in `px`, which means pixels. Pixels don't scale if, for example, a user makes the text larger, because a pixel on their screen is still the same size. If you size divs in `em`, meaning 'the width of the letter m in the current font' or `%` things should scale better. Also, once you're comfortable using CSS, try using a framework such as [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Check this CSS and HTML 
and just replace it with the existing one and please tell me

```
   body
    {
background-color:#603;  
}
.page
{
width:960px;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
div#hor
{

}
div#hor ul
{ 
list-style-type:none;
 }
div#ver
{
float:left;
}
 div#hor li
{  
float:left;
background-color:#603; 
border-radius:22px; 
}

div#ver
{

}
div#ver li
{
list-style-type:none; 
background-color:#603; 
border-radius:22px; 
margin:5px; 
}
div#hor a,div#ver a
{
text-decoration:none; 
 padding-left:32px;
 padding-right:32px;
 font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive; 
 line-height:100px;
display: block;
 line-height: 40px;
 color:#fff;
}
div#hor a:hover
{
background-color:#fff;color: #603;border-radius:22px; 
}
div#hor a:focus
{
background-color:#fff;color:#603;border-radius:22px; font-weight:bold;
}
div#ver
{
//position:relative; top:100px;
}
div#ver ul
{ 
position:relative;float:left;  
}
div#ver li
{
//float:none; margin-bottom:20px;
}

div#ver a:hover,div#ver a:focus
{
border-radius:22px;background-color:#fff;color: #603
}

div#ver a:focus
{
 font-weight:bold; 
}
```

//Html Part//

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"  />


</head>

<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="hor">
<ul>
<li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a  href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="ver"> 
<ul>
<li ><a href="#">Java</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Php</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Asp.net</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
<li><a  href="#">Iphone</a></li>
</ul>

 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou very much bhai :x it worked exactly da way i wanted ...that was so much help :)@amuk saxena............ could yu plz tell me what actually i shudnt be doing to avoid these kind of probz.

Comment: ur welcome, whenever you add this line


<div style="float:left; or float:right;"> sentence....
</div>
after closing this div tag, add this code too-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

this will avoid distortion of lines..

Comment: I mean to say after the first line of your page is complete and you want to start a new line, and if in the previous line you have added float:left then add the "clear:both" code...